# ORA-00937: not a single-group group function PL/SQL issue

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Firstly, I know ORA-000937 is a common issue, with an obvious answer, but I am yet to find any results that could point to a possible solution.

Quick Spec;
National TB/HIV report, based on patient medical records/encounters/visits and drug's provided. This is only a tiny portion of the report, which loops all patient drugs, and calculates most of it's figures off date calculations, we do not store historic/aggregated data, everything is aggregated when requested. I mention this because I expect a few suggestions to move away from GTT's and to rather use MVIEW's - I hear you, but no, not a solution.

Here is my problem, this is one of my queries populating a GTT, within a function, which stores aggregated results. I have structured my data collection in such away as to reduce server load as the medical table exceeds 12 million records. (Each patient has 3 per default).

Here is the GTT

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE EKAPAII.TEMP_ART_VISIT_MEDS
(
EPISODE_ID      NUMBER,
LAST_MEDS_DATE  DATE
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
NOCACHE;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX EKAPAII.TEMP_ART_VISIT_MEDS_PK ON EKAPAII.TEMP_ART_VISIT_MEDS
(EPISODE_ID);


ALTER TABLE EKAPAII.TEMP_ART_VISIT_MEDS ADD (
CONSTRAINT TEMP_ART_VISIT_MEDS_PK
PRIMARY KEY
(EPISODE_ID)
USING INDEX EKAPAII.TEMP_ART_VISIT_MEDS_PK
ENABLE VALIDATE);
```

And my simple insert query

```
INSERT INTO temp_art_visit_meds (EPISODE_ID, LAST_MEDS_DATE) 
SELECT episode_id, encounter_date + number_of_days
FROM (  SELECT enc_meds.episode_id,
MAX (enc_meds.encounter_date) encounter_date,
MAX (
CASE
WHEN (NVL (meds.number_of_days, 0) > 150)
THEN
90
ELSE
NVL (meds.number_of_days, 0)
END)
number_of_days
FROM temp_art_visit enc_meds,
vd_medication meds,
dl_drugs_episode_class dlc,
(  SELECT latest_meds_visit.episode_id,
MAX (latest_meds_visit.encounter_date)
   encounter_date
FROM temp_art_visit latest_meds_visit,
vd_medication latest_meds,
dl_drugs_episode_class dc
WHERE     latest_meds_visit.encounter_id =
       latest_meds.encounter_id
AND latest_meds.drug_id = dc.drug_id
AND dc.sd_drug_application_id = 8401
GROUP BY latest_meds_visit.episode_id) latest_meds
WHERE     enc_meds.encounter_id = meds.encounter_id
AND enc_meds.episode_id = latest_meds.episode_id
AND enc_meds.encounter_date =
latest_meds.encounter_date
AND meds.drug_id = dlc.drug_id
AND dlc.sd_drug_application_id = 8401
AND meds.active_flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY enc_meds.episode_id);
```

Now my error, is ORA-000937 not a single-group group function, but if I run this query in a normal editor window it works, but I get ORA-000937 when executing the select query in the package body itself, calling the function does not return any error, even though I have an exception block to handle any errors.

Any help will do, I do understand that this errors could occur only at runtime, and not at compile time? Or is it the fact that I am running the query from the pl/sql block?

Toad for Oracle version 12.5 - in all it's glory. (sarcasm)

Again, pardon me if this has already been asked/answered.

EDIT - SOLUTION

So, after a few hours of trouble shooting, I was able to understand why this error is being generated. Firstly, the fixed query;

```
INSERT INTO temp_art_visit_meds (EPISODE_ID, LAST_MEDS_DATE) 
SELECT enc_meds.episode_id , 
TRUNC( MAX (enc_meds.encounter_date)) + MAX (CASE WHEN (NVL (meds.number_of_days, 0) > 150) THEN 90 ELSE NVL (meds.number_of_days, 0) END) last_meds_date
FROM temp_art_visit enc_meds,
vd_medication meds,
dl_drugs_episode_class dlc,
(  SELECT latest_meds_visit.episode_id,
MAX (latest_meds_visit.encounter_date) encounter_date
FROM temp_art_visit latest_meds_visit,
vd_medication latest_meds,dl_drugs_episode_class dc
WHERE     latest_meds_visit.encounter_id = latest_meds.encounter_id
AND latest_meds.drug_id = dc.drug_id
AND dc.sd_drug_application_id = 8401
GROUP BY latest_meds_visit.episode_id) latest_meds
WHERE     enc_meds.encounter_id = meds.encounter_id
AND enc_meds.episode_id = latest_meds.episode_id
AND enc_meds.encounter_date = latest_meds.encounter_date
AND meds.drug_id = dlc.drug_id
AND dlc.sd_drug_application_id = 8401
AND meds.active_flag = 'Y'                              
GROUP BY enc_meds.episode_id,  meds.number_of_days, enc_meds.encounter_date;
```

It would appear that problem was due to the amount of sub-queries, I attempted to use different hint optimizers with no avail. If you look closely at the first query, you will notice I am basically aggregating results from aggregated results, so the column's encounter_date, episode_id, number_of_days are no longer 'available', so even if I added the appropriate GROUP BY clause to my last (outer) subquery, Oracle would not be able to group on those column names/identifiers.

I am not sure why this would fail only in a PACKAGE BODY, and did not return any SQLERR or SQLCODE when executed.

Happy days.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your code

Comment: The readability of your query is terrible because of two reasons: failure to use `WITH` clauses and failure to use explicit joins (`INNER JOIN ...`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - This was taken from the PL/SQL block, hence my question referring to the differences in executing a query from within a package body (i.e: selecting the select query, and running it) as opposed to running it from within a normal editor/query window

Comment: @popovitsj - I hear you, I am simply following the current 'coding standard', there are a total of 0 LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOIN's in any package on the systems I am working on. All queries are join in the where clause, being a dev with SQL background, I cannot agree with you more.

Comment: is this dynamic SQL ?

Comment: @OracleUser - definitely not.

Comment: Your query is perfectly fine. And it should _not_ throw an error in `PL/SQL` too. If syntax is wrong, it could be a compilation error, unless it is Dynamic. If you get this in run-time, then it means there's some procedure in your module, doing dynamic thing.

Comment: @OracleUser, thanks, took me a while to adjust from SQL to Oracle. I think I get what you are saying, I have a few things I can investigate now - possibly.

Comment: Maybe a completely different problem, but ... I stumbled upon ORA-979 several times, while the query obviously was OK. The trouble was always a particular query transformation done internally by the Oracle's query optimizer. At least try hinting your inner queries with the `no_merge` hint. That would be instead of `SELECT enc_meds.episode_id,` you do `SELECT /*+ no_merge */ enc_meds.episode_id,` and instead of `SELECT latest_meds_visit.episode_id,` you do `SELECT /*+ no_merge */ latest_meds_visit.episode_id,`

Comment: @nop77svk - Thanks for the help, I was starting to think I was the only one ", .I tried the hint optimizer(s) with no luck, in doing some tests using NO_MERGE, I was able to determine that the columns were not identifiable. I believe the issue would have been resolved if I had implemented a correlated subquery, as my inner query would execute once for every outer query.